# How to prove theorem about Gramian determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How to prove that  the vectors are linearly independent if and only if the Gram determinant is nonzero (if and only if the Gram matrix is nonsingular)?

**AND**

Prove that a linear relationship Euclidean or unitary vector space is necessary and sufficient to Gram determinant of these vectors equal zero.

I am stuck on it. Already thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $v \in V$ and try to write $v = \sum_i \alpha_i v_i$.
We have $\langle v, v_j \rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$. If the Gram matrix is invertible, then we can solve for $\alpha_i$ and so $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is a basis.

If the Gram matrix is singular, then any nonzero solution of the homogenous system will give a nonzero vector $v$ such that $\langle v, v_j \rangle = 0$ for all $j$ and so $v_1, \dots, v_n$ cannot be a basis (otherwise $\langle v, w \rangle = 0$ for all $w \in V$).